# White bar on the footer of my Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

A white bar appears bellow the footer of my Wordpress site. I try to see what it is with the Chrome developer tool and it looks like it is an iframe.

I don´t know how this happened but the problem was not there a few weeks ago. It does not happen on my chrome browser but when I try it in any other browser or PC I see the white bar.

The site is http://preposicionesdeplacer.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white bar you're seeing on some browsers is the body of your page. [image]

It changes along with the body if you test it.

I added the following attributes to `#colophon` and the effect disappears across all my browsers.

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its normal because below your footer you have several iframes. This one as you can see bellow has the display element set to no.

```
<iframe src="http://loadus.exelator.com/load//net.php?n=eJyVkmFLwzAQhv%2FKKK4f07Td5qbLirAO%2FLBvCoJIuSYxzWza0GS4%2FnuvdYIgAweBXN7k7rk3yVobNamkVpVnQRxMPrXw1Ri5jrOg8t7eRZHrG04M%2BMqDIrw1oxBhamZ8IU9asJhSugw7KXTHhqRp%2BjBNdjjqFoQh8iRr8G03JJ%2FFYTvd4cFtQmfTZKEwimmM0QEjinN5xMKv%2B33x%2FPy4fQs264G4Wf%2BrY24cgQbq3mvuSA9V246No55Z6HwjuwKr5y%2F5U36pMtQ452PncgseLrF0SUA0JzcClPTYdlNm582%2F%2FkcpyixD36FiNJ6FpWY36DE8MHqtTaKIaI9lLXmt%2BQdppI%2BsRlqm2lbVsmjQ5TddhmDs%2FVnm5vfK8euwIIg7WeIM3iRy7Ygd%2FkTmeysZfoNQOHsc3i8BWK3SZUrn5ewdYElXlM6TBZeLW1qKZP4D%2FgKO89UZ&amp;h=75343745526d1625180b3cc2f82b37c2&amp;ver=2" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: no;"></iframe>
```

So just put this and normally it will hide this iframe too :

```
<iframe src="http://loadus.exelator.com/load//net.php?n=eJyVkmFLwzAQhv%2FKKK4f07Td5qbLirAO%2FLBvCoJIuSYxzWza0GS4%2FnuvdYIgAweBXN7k7rk3yVobNamkVpVnQRxMPrXw1Ri5jrOg8t7eRZHrG04M%2BMqDIrw1oxBhamZ8IU9asJhSugw7KXTHhqRp%2BjBNdjjqFoQh8iRr8G03JJ%2FFYTvd4cFtQmfTZKEwimmM0QEjinN5xMKv%2B33x%2FPy4fQs264G4Wf%2BrY24cgQbq3mvuSA9V246No55Z6HwjuwKr5y%2F5U36pMtQ452PncgseLrF0SUA0JzcClPTYdlNm582%2F%2FkcpyixD36FiNJ6FpWY36DE8MHqtTaKIaI9lLXmt%2BQdppI%2BsRlqm2lbVsmjQ5TddhmDs%2FVnm5vfK8euwIIg7WeIM3iRy7Ygd%2FkTmeysZfoNQOHsc3i8BWK3SZUrn5ewdYElXlM6TBZeLW1qKZP4D%2FgKO89UZ&amp;h=75343745526d1625180b3cc2f82b37c2&amp;ver=2" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Tell me if that worked well for you, as for me it hides the iframe

Comment: Why do I have that iframe? Could I get ride of it? Or it is something neccesary for my theme? Thanks